# Select columns from table in schema different than public

Tags: sql, postgresql

In my PostgreSQL database I have table that is inside `import` schema. When I want to get all data from the column I do:

```
select * from import.master_plan
```

This query works fine. But when I try to for example get only title column values:

```
select import.master_plan.title from import.master_plan;
```

it returns:

```
ERROR:  column master_plan.title does not exist
LINE 1: select import.master_plan.title from import.master_plan;
               ^
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "master_plan.  title".
```

I've also tried:

```
select title from import.master_plan;
```

but this also not works. I'm using PostgreSQL 10. How can I fix that?

Comment: Can you check the schema if the column exists? I tried it on my Postgres 10 and it works.

Example: SELECT
  name
  FROM schema_1.users;

Also, in your example you are calling table 'master' and then calling 'master_plan'. Is this on purpose?

Comment: When I wrapped my column into '' then it works fine.

Comment: So the column name contained a non-alphanumeric?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that you use a table alias instead:

```
select mp.title
from import.master_plan mp;
```

This is much easier to read and to type.

Judging from the error message, though, the name seems to have leading spaces.  Something like:

```
select mp."   title"
from import.master_plan mp;
```

might work.  If this is the case, alter the table and rename the column.